# How to get the version for lifecycle libraries in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-lifecycle

In Android documentation it's written that we might add dependencies for ViewModel into Gradle like this:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$lifecycle_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
```

However, I really cannot find the way to specify the lifecycle_version. I've already tried with File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies -> Add button doesn't work.

It may be too straightforward, but I really can't find a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a variable directly into your app level build.gradle file:

```
 def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
```

Some projects configure this in the project level build.gradle file like so:

```
ext {
    dagger = '2.16'
}
```

And use it like this:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${dagger}"
```

Finally, if you don't want to use variables you can simply use the version name instead:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
```

You can check what is the current version in the Arch Components [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components) and [notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes).

For lifecycle the current version is **1.1.1** if you're not using AndroidX

Comment: thank you very much, the 1st line in the docs ran out of my eyes

Comment: glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define version.

```
android {
    ....
    ext {
        lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    }
}



dependencies {
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
  }
```

Or just use

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
```

Check [Architecture Components Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes) for latest version and new features.

Comment: thanks so much, I wanted to know where did you get the version from ?

Comment: For reference, the ext block does not need to be in the android block. I will often put all my versions in an ext block in my root build file.